# Which is the best for xml parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got xml file which is about 400 mb. in size.

I want to choose the best xml parser for that.

I need to parse and display the data.

current we have NSXMLParser, libxml2, TBXMLParser, TouchXMLParser, KissXMLParser, TinyXMLParser and GDataXMLParser

Which is best among this ?  for the 400 mb size file xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends, if you want a sax parser i would say NSXMLParser fits the bill completely. However libxml2 has the advantage of being a DOM Parser. Since your file is very large using a DOM parser would result in heavy memory usage.

Comment: Okay  so i need to go with sax parser.

Answer (score 0):

What is the preferred and commonly used in business Applications is NSXmlparser.From last one year i am working on it.Its better than others. But depends on your requirements.